# When loading parent window of framed pagefrom different domain causes permission denied in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a login paged that is framed with a parent with a different domain. If login is successful, I am loading the following page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body 
        onload="parent.window.location=':"'http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/joomla15/index.php/logged-in-welcome-page.html?user=test&passw=test'":'"
    >
    </body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly in FF and Chrome, but I get permission denied in IE. I was looking and IE (at least older versions) does not allow the iframe to update the parent using the windows.onload. Any ideas?  I was thinking I could possible make the login check an ajax call and then do a redirect after sucess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to work around this.  I created a link with an id to the forwarded page in an invisible div and after the login was validated, did document.getElementById('myLink').click().  Works perfectly.